# Simple rectangle in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rect, unity3d-2dtools

There's plenty of tutorials which explain how to add and manage image objects. But what if I want to add simple rectangle with plain white color? May I do it similar to adding 3D objects? I see no rectangle option under 2D Object in GameObject menu.

I know that I may do it by script, but isn't there any simpler solution? Or maybe I should use 3D Object Cube instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a *rectangle* (ie a 2D cuboid) you add a 3D object that is a **Quad** which is a 3D object with a size of 0 in one plane, in effect making it a 2D sheet.

See also:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PrimitiveObjects.html

Quads are most often used as backdrops to 2D games. Once you have the quad you can then change its material properties to set it as a single plain colour.

Comment: Yes! That's what I've been looking for!
But It looks like I need to add a light source to camera for such objects. All image type objects are natural bright, instead of Quad objects, which are dimmed a lot. Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: no, you can use absolute lighting by selecting the Quad object, goto the **material / mesh renderer --> shader --> unlit** and there will be a number of choices, typically you can choose "texture" or for your question you can use ***"color"*** which will display the quad as an unlit (but displayed at absolute intensity) colour value. @Lukis

Comment: Yay!! It works like a charm! So every instance of material is constant? If i would like to modify "whiteMaterial" (for example), do I have to duplicate it and change the single parameter to value I want? There is no possibility to change it's value for particular object which uses the material?

Comment: As far as I know, you need a set of different static materials, for different textures and colours, but if you're looking at plain colour objects then you can use the **mesh renderer --> shader --> unlit --> color** and then just select the colour that you want the object to be. This can then easily be changed via code, too. @Lukis

Comment: Unfortunately "shader" option is... shaded unless I drop any material from assets there. Then I may edit, but it edits the material which causes that every instance of this material will be changed.

Comment: hmmm, I have a Quad in one game I am constructing and selecting Shader->unlit->color removes the texture and replaces it with a solid colour value. This is just a quad object not a prefab or anything. I'm not sure what else to recommend to you, try here: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/graphics @Lukis

Comment: That's ok. You helped me a lot!